# Android prevent app from querying an empty database on startup

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm building a simple todo/task app in which tasks are presented in a Recycler/card view layout and upon the selection of a task the user is taken a "detailed" view of that specific task. I'm testing my app using the Genymotion emulator. My problem is the app crashes immediately upon startup with a NPE.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.api.client.util.DateTime.toString()' on a null object reference
            at com.github.idclark.forgetmenot.TaskAdapter.onBindViewHolder(TaskAdapter.java:35)
            at com.github.idclark.forgetmenot.TaskAdapter.onBindViewHolder(TaskAdapter.java:17)
```

Although I'm not entirely sure, I think this is because I haven't entered any data into the database yet. The database is first queried from the fragment that is inflated by my Main activity.

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        Activity mActivity;
        RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
        TaskAdapter taskAdapter;
        AddFloatingActionButton mFabView;
        CheckBox mCheckBox;

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cardList);
            mFabView = (AddFloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.normal_plus);

            mFabView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent createTaskIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), EditActivity.class);
                    startActivity(createTaskIntent);
                }
            });

            taskAdapter = new TaskAdapter(new TaskTableController(getActivity()).getAllTasksForUser());
            return rootView;
        }
```

My `TaskAdapter` expects an `ArrayList<Task>`

```
public class TaskAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskAdapter.TaskViewHolder> {

    private List<Task> taskList;
    OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener;

    public TaskAdapter(List<Task> taskList) {
        this.taskList = taskList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return taskList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TaskViewHolder taskViewHolder, int i) {
        Task task = taskList.get(i);
        taskViewHolder.mTitle.setText(task.getTitle());
        taskViewHolder.mUpdated.setText(task.getUpdated().toString());
        if (task.getStatus().equals("completed")) {
            taskViewHolder.mStatus.setChecked(true);
        } else taskViewHolder.mStatus.setChecked(false);

    }

    @Override
    public TaskViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.tasklist_layout, viewGroup, false);

        return new TaskViewHolder(itemView);
    }
```

The actual query to the database looks like

```
public List<Task> getAllTasksForUser() {
        final String QUERY_ALL_RECORDS = "SELECT * FROM " + TaskEntry.TABLE_NAME;

        List<Task> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(QUERY_ALL_RECORDS, null);
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                Task task = new Task();
                int TaskId = cursor.getColumnIndex(TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_ID);
                task.setId(cursor.getString(TaskId));
                task.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_TITLE)));
                task.setDue(new DateTime(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_DUE))));
                task.setNotes(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_NOTES)));
                taskList.add(task);
            }
        } else return taskList;
        db.close();
        return taskList;
    }
```

When the app is first installed on the emulator, there is no data in the database, which I think is what is causing the NPE. How do I handle this situation so that if there is no data my fragment just displays an empty list (ie blank). I'm already checking to see if `cursor.getCount()` is greater than 0, if it's not return an empty list to the adapter. What am I missing to get rid of this NPE?

Comment: The exception says that `task.getUpdated()` returns `null`, probably because that's exactly what is stored in the database. If there were no data, `onBindViewHolder` would not be called because the task list would be empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crash most likely is at the following line:

```
    taskViewHolder.mUpdated.setText(task.getUpdated().toString());
```

`task.getUpdate()` returns null and your app crashes.
I don't see where you call setUpdated. It could be that one of your setters does that, or it could be that you forgot to put a setter in your code.

On a bit unrelated note: if your task list is empty you don't close neither cursor nor your database.